# Cassandra Triggers on a subset of nodes?

Tags: cassandra

Triggers are defined on a table at the keyspace level and so I'm guessing every replica for the table needs to have access to the trigger class.

Is it possible to have a given DC with the trigger class resident whilst the other DCs don't?

It is possible to only have a subset of the replicas within a DC have the trigger class?

I suppose a quick and dirty workaround would be to have "empty" classes on the nodes upon which we don't want any triggering but this seems a real hack -- hence my question.

Thanks in advance.